# API Connect: APIs which are having 'map' in assembly, are getting failed locally

Tags: loopback, apiconnect

I am fresher in loopback. I have import api from https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/airavata/sandbox/xbaya-web/test/Calculator.wsdl

in Services section like

[image]

after that i create a path 'addWsdl'

and Assemble that path with calculator add function like below

[image]

i am getting below error when calling the addWsdl function.

```
{ "name": "Error", "message": "Cannot find module 'map'" }
```

Thanks advance.

if you need any clarification pls comment

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is because you do not have the NPM module map installed on your local machine. Can you please install it by using the npm CLI:

```
npm install map
```

You can check to see if/where you currently have it installed locally as well as the version by using the following command:

```
npm list map
```